# Applying multiple autofilter at once in Excel

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have written a simple VBScript to filter the column values based on the input value. There are multiple columns in the sheet and currently I am filtering only on one column. But I do have to include other columns also in the filter criteria.

Suppose, I have to include first column(Capitals) also in the filter. And this column has values `Y,X,Z`. And Except `Z`, I have to select all values. So,first it will be filtered on the ProcessName and then on the Capitals column.After that it should be filtered based on third column where the value can be New or Blanks.Not sure how to add or condition there.

My current code :

```
strPath="C:\Users\Desktop\Code.xlsx"

Dim ProcessName

ProcessName=Trim(InputBox("Process Name:"))
Set objExcel= CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible= True

objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strPath)

With objExcel.Activeworkbook.Sheets("All")

    .Range("A1").AutoFilter 19,"="&ProcessName
    .Range("A1").AutoFilter 1,"<>"&"z" 
    .Range("A1").AutoFilter 7,"="&"New" or "="&"(Blanks)" <-- throwing error 

End With
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you tried running it? It should work.

Comment: Can you please check my updated code? I am facing some problem with Or condition...

Comment: Update code as .Range("A1").AutoFilter 7,Array("New","(Blanks)"),7 . and it's working...